# spacing between cells io9.2 objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create spacing between table view cells like this:

[image]

I have 1 section and a dynamic number of rows per section for my tableview. So far I have set my content view to clear like this in my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I have also created a view within my content view, but I'm not sure how to set those values or manipulate the subview so that it appears as though there is spacing. If there's an easier way to create spacing I'm open to those suggestions as well.

Comment: Create `xib` with custom cell, set necessary content padding there ...

Answer (score 0):

Set the group background to clear color and the controller's background to the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

1) Set the tableviews background colour to clear.

2) Set the cells background colour to clear as well.

3) Add a view(suppose "myView") with the background colour you need on top of the cell such that the height of the view is less than the rows height (e.g. myView.height = 90 and row height is 100).

4) Add the rest of your views as subviews of myView.

You will achieve your desired result.